# zero-beta portfolio $z$ solves optimization problem

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio

Consider a market with $p$ risky assets with expected return $\mu \neq k 1$ and positive definite covariance matrix $C$. Let $z$ be a zero-beta portfolio w.r.t the market portfolio $x_M$.

Show that z solves the following optimization problem:

$$\min_{y\in R^p}\frac{1}{2}y^TCy$$ such that  $1^Ty=1$ and     $ x_M^TCy=0$

At first I just checked shortly if $z$ fulfills the constraints. Since $z$ is efficient and zero-beta portfolio it follows that $x_M^TCz=Cov[x_M,z]=0$ and also $1^Tz=1$.Now I'm not a 100% sure on how to show that z has the minimum variance. In a previous part of the exercise I did the Lagrange-function and the KKT-conditions for this problem, but I don't think I need to use those to show that z is the solution.

Comment: The thing you are minimizing is half the variance of z. So z is the minimum variance portfolio which satisfies the two constraints.

Comment: I don't really understand why the variance of z has to have the smallest variance with those constraints though.

Comment: Under further consideration, since z is efficient it is a given that z has the lowest variance for a specific expectation. Since it's on the efficient frontier. Thanks for the help!